# Not sure if HTML is using CSS file because changes made to CSS file do not show up on webpage. What do I do?

Tags: html, css

I am tasked with making an alert on the "Beta: Empty Bedspaces" and "Beta: Hall Roster With Empty Beds" reports. I have to put the alert in at the top of the page. I want it to be centered and not take up the whole width of the page.

Putting in inline styles work, but I am not sure if it is reading the CSS file. Considering this is for a job, I can't really move the file itself around, and I am 99% sure it's in a good file location as that's where my coworkers/boss already has it.

HTML code:

```
{% extends 'reports_templates/base.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block extra-head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{% static 'css/empty_bedspaces.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
<title>Empty Bed Spaces</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="alert">
  <strong>Note:</strong> Some of the rooms below may not be available for assignment.
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.container div {
  margin: 1%;
}

#specific-table tr th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

th.title {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.alert-danger {
    font-size: 72px;
}
```

If I do:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin: 45%" >
  <strong>Note:</strong> Some of the rooms below may not be available for assignment.
</div>
```

It makes it take up an adequate amount of page space. Also, keep in mind this is not nearly all the code. I didn't want to paste a huge file.

[Here is a picture of how it looks so far with just the alert div.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJhMm.png)

Comment: Try to clear your cache and then reload the page and see if it takes effect

Comment: Right-Click "inspect page" in your browser and have a look under section "network" if the css file is loaded.

Comment: @nologin it looks to be there

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton idk how to do that exactly

Comment: @HelanaBrock Search google "[insert browser here] clear cache"

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thank you so much! That worked. To think I've been pulling my hair out about it for like 2 hours... guess it's all part of the learning process :)

Comment: @HelanaBrock You're welcome! Cache is so useful for the user, but sometimes it's a nightmare for the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your cache, most browsers: CTRL+SHIFT+R. While developing, I would also recommend disabling caching locally in your development panel. In Chrome it will be F12 > Network Tab > Check Disable Cache. You may need to restart your browser to force the changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, you could give it `class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2 text-center".`